# How to add icons to GUI contributing plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a plugin that adds some actions to a submenu in eclipse. 
The problem is that when the plugin is installed in eclipse...I can't see the icons of this menus.

My plugin.xml looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
      <objectContribution
            adaptable="true"
            id="Plugin.objectContribution1"
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
         <action
               class="plugin.Menus.Menu1"
               icon="icons/rsz_21.png"
               id="Plugin.action1"
               label="Menu 1..."
               menubarPath="team.main/group2">
         </action>
         <action
               class="plugin.Menus.Menu2"
               icon="icons/rsz_21.png"
               id="Plugin.Menu2"
               label="Menu 2..."
               menubarPath="team.main/group2">
         </action>
         <action
               class="Menus.Menu3"
               icon="icons/rsz_21.png"
               id="Plugin.action3"
               label="Menu 3..."
               menubarPath="team.main/group2">
         </action>
         <action
               class="Menus.Menu4"
               icon="icons/rsz_21.png"
               id="Plugin.Menu4"
               label="Menu 4..."
               menubarPath="team.main/group2">
            <enablement>
               <not>
                  <objectClass
                        name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                  </objectClass>
               </not>
            </enablement>
         </action>
      </objectContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants">
      <deleteParticipant
            class="Plugin.DeleteParticipant"
            id="Plugin.deleteParticipant1"
            name="Delete_file_on_server">
         <enablement>

         </enablement>
      </deleteParticipant>
   </extension>


</plugin>
```

When I run it from the developing instance I'm able to see the icons....just when I install it in Eclipse I can't see them.

Are there other things that need to be done in order to get this working ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your `build.properties` file. The 'icons' directory must be included in the bin.includes list.

So the file might look something like this:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.properties,\
               plugin.xml,\
               icons/
```